# Interruption Comma "yet then somehow"?

Tags: commas, adverb-position

Here are the examples:

> He repeated the experiment in exactly the same way yet expect different results.

> He repeated the experiment in exactly the same way then somehow expect different results.

These can be combined for effect:

> He repeated the experiment in exactly the same way yet then somehow expecting different results.

According to the rules of commas, to my understanding, both "then" and "somehow" are interruptions and can safely be omitted, but It seems to me that they are separate interruptions. So, do I separate them by a comma or not? Or was my analysis wrong all together?

> ...yet, then, somehow, ... or  ...yet, then somehow, ...

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure 'then' adds anything at all to the sentence. I'd just use _yet_ to mark the improbablility involved. And actually, I'd match 'and yet expected' to 'repeated'.

Comment: Well, I know. I'm asking this because I'm preparing for a transcription job, so I can't control what the people say, and they said it. I'm still not used to commas; They are giving me a nightmares, LOL.

Comment: This is a rather unusual expression, and I'm not sure there are grammatical rules for it. I'd put the commas in where the speaker paused (if they did).

Comment: I agree with @EdwinAshworth that the word ***then*** adds nothing, and is therefore *completely* redundant here. But imho it's not the word ***yet*** that emphasises the "improbability" of getting a different result. It's the word ***somehow*** that injects a "disdainful" tone to the utterance. The speaker can't imagine ***how*** the subject could possibly justify "expecting" something to happen differently, given that the cited utterance is effectively a rephrasing of [***a famous definition of insanity***.](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2017/03/23/same/)

Comment: See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=yet+expecting+different+results%2Cbut+expecting+different+results&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), showing that the vast majority of people use contrastive conjunction ***but*** in the cited context, rather than (relatively old-fashioned, literary) ***yet***.

Comment: "FF It's interesting that 'somehow' works in the pre-verb position. It's semantically a transferred usage; 'yet expected the results to somehow be different'.

Comment: If this is for a transcript, you won't get to choose the words that are used (quite the opposite), so debating that is academic. Spoken English is going to be very different from written English, so you'll get a lot more meandering sentences and people cutting themselves off. In that case, you'll end up placing commas to make sense of the changes in inflection. You'll see things like "I wouldn't--not that we agree on much, but I wouldn't say, for all he intended--I wouldn't say that that was what was going through his mind at that time, if I can say that." (Actual quote).

Answer (score -3):

I would write it

> He repeated the experiment in exactly the same way yet, then somehow, expecting different results.

**Yet** and **then somehow** are both conjunctions, and an alternative is offered so it is the same as

"I'm not sure what is in there. They are probably spanners or, and as well as, screwdrivers."